# How to write audio stream to file in python3

Tags: python, websocket, vonage

I am working with Nexmo. I would like to save live stream Nexmo call audio to my disk. 
I have implemented web socket to read Nexmo's stream. Please find below the code where I append audio to an existing audio file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# WS server example

import asyncio
import websockets

async def nexmoServer(websocket, path):
    audioData = await websocket.recv()

    input_filename = "sample_harshit.wav"
    output_filename = "new_file.wav"
    ifile = open(input_filename,'rb')
    ofile = open(output_filename, 'wb')
    data = audioData
    while data:
        ofile.write(data)
        data = ifile.read(1024*1024)
    ofile.close()
    ifile.close()
```

The audio file's length is updated but audio data is not written in the file.

Comment: Try ofile.append(data)

Comment: @N00b , it gives me error saying "AttributeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object has no attribute 'append'"

Comment: You need to loop through all the audio frames received from the websocket. This will require `async for message in websocket:` instead of `await websocket.recv()` which will only receive a single frame.

Comment: I'd also recommend removing all your code relating to `ifile` which should help you to understand what is going wrong with your function.

Answer (score 1):

Atleast this is working fine:

```
def nexmoServer():
    input_filename = "a.wav"
    output_filename = "b.wav"
    ifile = open(input_filename,'rb')
    ofile = open(output_filename, 'wb')
    data = ifile.read(1024*1024)
    while data:
        ofile.write(data)
        data = ifile.read(1024*1024)
    ofile.close()
    ifile.close()

nexmoServer()
```